# When running getting: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I get this error when running the code, my research says its something about send not being available on it or not defined, I don't fully understand it or how to fix it though.

The code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Client, Collection, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] })

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const channel = client.channels.cache.get('997960087249371136');

do {
  sleep(1000)
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  
  if(number = 1) {

    channel.send("Carrier under attack!")
    
  } else if(number = 2) {

    channel.send("Carrier leak detected in lower quaters!")
    
  } else if(number = 3) {

    channel.send("All is quiet, for now.")
    
  } else if(number = 4) {

    channel.send("Unidentified aircraft entering our airspace!")
    
  } else {
    console.log("The impossible is possible!")
  } 
}
while(true);
```

I know the channels do exist.

Comment: It means `channel` is `undefined`. Is this all your code? Are you trying to call this without an event handler? Then the `client` is not yet ready.

Comment: Yes it is the full code, I think I might be calling it without an event handeller. I’ll try it in the morning as it’s late for me and see if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just created the client, you haven't logged in with your token yet, this is why "client.channels.cache" is empty and contains no channels yet. To fix this you have to put everything on the "ready" event

Also there's some other problems on your code:

1. You have to async/await the "sleep" function or it's useless
2. On the if conditions, you have to check with === or ==, not = [see here why](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-and-in-javascript2/)
3. 1000 is way too short (1000 millisecondes is 1 second) posting 1 message/s is api request spam. Try using 4 or 5 seconds instead.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Client, Collection, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] })

client.on('ready', async () =>{
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get('997960087249371136');

  do {
    await sleep(1000)
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  
    if(number == 1) return channel.send("Carrier under attack!")
    else if(number == 2) return channel.send("Carrier leak detected in lower quaters!")
    else if(number == 3) return channel.send("All is quiet, for now.")
    else if(number == 4) return channel.send("Unidentified aircraft entering our airspace!")
    else return channel.send("The impossible is possible!")
  } while(true);
})

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

client.login("YOUR TOKEN")
```

Comment: When doing that I get
 ```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/HMS/index.js:12:36)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```
The code is at /commands/status.js if that is of any use, and the send bits say the same thing.

Comment: But this error has nothing to do with your problem in this question, if my answer fixed the original problem, approve it with the green checkmark and ask a new question !

Comment: it did not though

Comment: there's no lign 12 in my code or yours. I don't know what you added but it's not supposed to be there, just copy my code and paste it in your main file to understand

Comment: Says in the index, not this.